# How to have a `Post` table with multiple possible contents?

Tags: sql, database-design

How to have a `Post` table with multiple possible contents?

For example, a post can be a question post or a pool post like Facebook status posts. That means each of them requires different columns in the database but still, they are a Post and have the same columns like `like counts` and `comments`.

If the differences would be much more than 20 columns in each post type, then how would be a proper way to build that kind of table in `SQL` without creating a second Post table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a post table with a post_id primary key, all of the columns that are common to all "Post" types, and a column called "post_type".

Then, For each type of post, create a table for that type of post.  Each of these tables should have "post_id" as both a primary key and a foreign key to the "post" table, and all of the columns that are unique to that post type.

You really shouldn't try to do this with a single table.

Comment: I didn't get why "Each of these tables should have "post_id" bot primary and foreign key". I think it should only be as a foreign key. Could you please explain this part?

Comment: It's a primary key because it uniquely identifies the post, regardless of what the post type is.  It is a foreign key because it creates a one to one relationship between each generic "post" record and each more specfic "post type" record.  One of the easiest ways to create a one-to-one relationship is to make the same column a primary key and a foreign key.

I think of this as a way to sort of implement object inheritance in sql.    Eash of your "post_type" objects is inherting fields from the post object and then extending the post object.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! I think the same `Posts` row can be selected by different tables in this schema. This leads to one `Posts` row with relation to multiple different content tables, but there should be only one. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: I think the only way to prevent that is in your program logic.  I don't think there is a way in the database to prevent multiple post types from referencing the same post row.   You might be able to use an on insert trigger, but I try to avoid triggers unless they are absolutely necessary.